# NodeJs Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, http

I run `node myserver.js` that contains the code bellow, and after 40-50sec I get the error(bellow the code). Why do I get an error when nothing is happening?

```
var options = {
    host: 'google.com',
    port: '80',
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': 'post_data.length'
    }
 };

 var subscribeRequest = require('http').request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('send request');
 }).on('error', function(err){console.log(err.stack)});
```

after 40-50sec I get this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Comment: This also happens when the server refuse your request. If you e.g. do many request to a server, they might block you after a while and will cause this error.

Answer (score 5):

I see at least two things wrong here:

1. You're not ending your request. When you use `http.request()` you have to call `.end()` on the request object returned when you are done sending any data so that the server knows there is no more data coming. `http.get()` automatically calls `.end()` for you because there are no bodies with GET requests.
2. `'Content-Length': 'post_data.length'` should be `'Content-Length': post_data.length`

Comment: But I never call this function? I don't understand when does it fire, You are right about number 2. Can you provide code snippet for 1.?

Comment: Assuming you do in fact have `post_data`, you'd do `subscribeRequest.end(post_data);`. That will send your form data and signal the end of your request. Then you should get some kind of response from the server.

Comment: @mscdex
I am doing calender event using express js and postmark smtp service
I am getting the same error even though i have declared res.end() at the and the error what i m getting is 
{[Error:connect ETIMEDOUT 50.31.225.155:2525]
code:'ECONNECTION',
errno:'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall:'connect',
address:'50.31.225.155',
port:2525,
command:'CONN'
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `subscribeRequest.end()` after declaring your request! If you don't do it, your request will never be sent